# Including $(this).data() in AJAX call when opening Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am trying to send the `data` object with an AJAX request when opening up a Magnific Popup. However, it seems like `$(this)` is not being translated correctly within the plugin.

Consider this code:

```
<div class="my-div">
  <a href="/path/to/file.php" data-name="John" data-location="Boston">Click here</a>
</div>

$('.my-div a').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  ajax: {
    settings: {
      data: $(this).data()
    }
  }
});
```

The data object is not properly returned. However, if I replace the data line with this:

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

Then I'm able to reference those objects in the `$_GET`.

---

**EDIT:** To further the fact that `$(this)` is not functioning properly within `magnificPopup`, I changed the data line to:

```
data: { href: $(this).attr('href') }
```

Which still returns nothing.

---

Everything I've done seems to point at `$(this)` not being respected within the plugin. How can I get the `data` objects from the original anchor tag and pass them on to the AJAX request?

Comment: I guess you have to mention the key in the .data() method.
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: No, a simple `.data()` will return all `data-*` values as a JavaScript object. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7nvgL/

Comment: Is it because you are passing an object without a required parameter name. Try data: { myObj: $(this).data() } . This might pass the object with the name myObj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data-attribute value of clicked element to ajax settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846457/pass-data-attribute-value-of-clicked-element-to-ajax-settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.my-div a').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax',
      elementParse: function(item) {
           this.st.ajax.settings = item.el.data();
      }
});
```

Comment: And then how do you access these values from within the popup?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best way to call an ajax response with data attributes in the request is simply to call an ajax request on click instead of directly calling magnificpopup. Then simply insert the response into a standard inline mfp.

```
$('a.popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    ajax: {
        settings: {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax.php',
            data: {
                action : 'ajax_action',
                postid : this.currItem.el.data('id')
                // this doesn't actually work because 'this.currItem'
                // is only accessible in a callback
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Do this instead:

```
$('a.popup').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action : 'ajax_action',
            postid : $(this).data('id'),
            //$(this).data() works because it's a standard AJAX call
        },
        success: function(data){
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                type: 'inline',
                items: {
                    src: data
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
data: { name:$(this).data('name'), location:$(this).data('location')  }
```

Comment: You are incorrect, `$(this).data()` does capture all the `data-*` elements and returns them as a JavaScript object. Regardless, your answer does not work.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't solve the problem. `$(this)` seems to absent while inside the `magnificPopup` call. I'm looking for an alternative way to get the `data` attribute's values.